# Image Dpi using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can I know an image dpi (horizontal and vertical resolution) using javascript ?

Comment: Are you just looking for the image's size in pixels or the actual resolution of the image?

Comment: The actual resolution of the image

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476815/can-you-access-sceen-displays-dpi-settings-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: @Tim, the question you link to asks how to get the user's screen resolution, not an image DPI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXIF parsing extension from Blueimp's Load Image library, https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#user-content-meta-data-parsing.

```
loadImage.parseMetaData(file, function(meta) {
    if (!meta.exif) { return; }

    var resX = meta.exif.get('XResolution');
    var resY = meta.exif.get('YResolution');
});
```

There is also the exif-js library (https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js), but I cannot vouch for how well it works (haven't used it).

Answer (score -6):

I think DPI is not a property of an image. DPI is a measurement used when printing.

Anyhow... You can get width and height of an image with something like this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png";

//show width and height in alert-popup
alert("Width: "+image.width+", Height: "+image.height);
```

The img element is always same size as the image itself, if you do not specify width and/or height. That's why this should work :)

Comment: I don't know why this got all those downvotes.  It works.

Comment: Unsure how this "works". It just returns the dimensions of an image, not the DPI which is a property of every image wether it's used for web or print or anything else