# Better way to get my screensize in inches?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the best way to get my screen size in inches. I'm testing it on a Galaxy S10, which has a screen size of 6.1". However, if you test this code below (which is also **[in this codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/full/ZEWdMMZ)**), I get a result of **3.75" x 7.92"**.

Using the `floor()` method rounds it down, but not to the 6.1" that I should get.

Any ideas?

```js
//get screen inches
function getScreenSizeInches() {
    const dpi_x = dpi.offsetWidth;
    const dpi_y = dpi.offsetHeight;
    const inchesWidth = (screen.width / dpi_x).toFixed(2);
    const inchesHeight = (screen.height / dpi_y).toFixed(2);

    inchesSize.textContent = `${inchesWidth}" x ${inchesHeight}"`;
}
getScreenSizeInches();
```

```css
#dpi {
    height: 1in; 
    width: 1in; 
    left: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dpi"></div>
<h2>Screen Size: <span id="inchesSize"></span></h2>
```

Comment: what are the dpi figures (simple change to output them as well)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/279749/3193156 or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/476815/3193156

Comment: They both return as 96.