# how to detecting PPI in WEB?

Tags: responsive-design, ppi

problem: screen resolution and screen size not proportional
It called pixel per inch(PPI)
for example we can have same resolution on different screen sizes
1366px768 can be on 11" notebook, 15.4 laptop or 18" desktop
and 1 pixel isn't the same on different screens.
So if we put font-size for example 14px it will be less on notebook even on desktop

I open those question because haven't found the solution.

I tried 
html meta name="viewport"
css cm, in, @media, @viewreport 
js svg, navifation.userAgent and other tools

I looked at: 
[How can I find out a web page viewers pixels per inch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252030/how-can-i-find-out-a-web-page-viewers-pixels-per-inch)
[Getting the physical screen dimensions / dpi / pixel density in Chrome on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi)
[Mobile web: how to get physical pixel size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456455/mobile-web-how-to-get-physical-pixel-size)
 and other questions

How can we set the same size on different screens or how we can detect PPI in WEB?

**UPD.** So it isn't any solution:
[Getting the physical screen dimensions / dpi / pixel density in Chrome on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi?answertab=votes#tab-top)