# Is there a list of what device has what abstracted dpi and screen size?

Tags: android

As I understand, the matching dpi and size qualifiers for the device are based not on actual screen properties (physical dpi and size), but instead on what was predefined by the device manufacturer.

Is there a list of what abstract dpi/sizes are for different devices?

Comment: Yes: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/ feel free to comment with your device

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding.  This isn't a free-for-all where manufacturers can pick whatever they want.  It is true that they have some flexibility in picking the density, but not a lot -- ultimately the density combined with the physical screen resolution explicitly results in a screen bucket and the way that mapping happens is specified by the platform.  Also, the density selected is almost always going to be what you would expect give the actual DPI of the device.  A manufacturer may push that with going to a higher density -- this results in a larger UI on the screen and likely a move down to a lower screen size bucket -- but this is extremely rare.

So.  A 320x240 screen can only be a small size low density screen.  Nothing else.

Devices with 480x320 screens are universally normal size medium density.

Devices with 480x800 (or x852) screens are the vast majority of the time a normal size high density.  There are some rare devices with a large 480x800 screen like the Dell Streak -- these are a medium density screen and large bucket.  You can tell a device is like this because...  well, it has a large screen. :}

The devices shipping with qHD screens can't go up to the xhdpi bucket (try it, you end up with a screen too small to be compatible), so these are still high density and they are also still normal size because they aren't sufficiently large to be in the large bucket.  In other words, this is just another phone screen with a little more space for layout.

The 10" tablets you see are 1280x800 or 1280x720.  These are mdpi screens, and in the xlarge bucket.

Android 3.2 is supporting 7" screens which are generally 1024x720 mdpi.  These end up in the large size bucket.

There are of course many other screens you can imagine, but I don't know off-hand of devices shipping with them and given that we have already covered small, normal, large, and xlarge there is really nothing too interesting about them.  For example a 640x480 phone size screen would be hdpi density and small screen bucket.

Comment: Here is a blog post that just went up that may provide further useful information: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Is there any way to get the _actual_ ppi of a device (or at least the physical screen dimensions in inches or mm to calculate the actual ppi)? I haven't been able to find a way...

Comment: Forgot to mention xdpi and ydpi in DisplayMetrics, but those do not return correct values...

Comment: Yes don't use xdpi and ydpi, they are not reliable.  Sorry there is currently no way to get the physical dpi.

Comment: @hackbod Very informative answer, I designed my app consulting sizes and dpi from your answer and it is running 'beautifully' on a lot of devices. One exception is Samsung galaxy note: whose bucket is xlarge and dpi is more than hdpi.[from http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note-4135.php]. What do you say about this

Comment: I have never used a Galaxy Note, so I can't address that, and your link doesn't work.  If it is xhdpi (which is the only thing above hdpi), then for that screen resolution the only compatible screen size is normal (it ends up being the same as the Galaxy Nexus).

Comment: I wish that screen dimensions for individual devices were stated explicitly not just in px but also in dp in the specs so we wouldn't have to calculate density buckets and manually do px-to-dp conversions every time.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this page : [Wikipedia : List of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density)

AFAIK, most of the time, dpi and ppi are the same, and it next generalized to HDPI/MDPI/LDPI ( see [Android screen ranges](http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-ranges.png) ).
There are just a very little number of exceptions.

Comment: I need abstracted density (ldpi/mdpi/hdpi), not actual physical ppi.

Comment: For example, what exact devices are guaranteed to have "small" screen size? (so I can request them for testing my app)

Comment: the HTC WildFire has a small screen with low dpi

Comment: ASUS Eee Pad is going to have ldpi xlarge screen but it's not released yet AFAIK. It's actual dpi is about 160.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to be helpful as it is specific to Android: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Comment: It contains actual sizes, not abstracted qualifiers.

Comment: the page has been deleted!

Answer (score 3):

Since latest I/O 2015 here is the list that you can use
https://www.google.com/design/tool/devices/

Answer (score 2):

The size data comes from Wikipedia, and for a better understanding of Pixel Density, check out this great post by Teehan+Lax.

[Screen Sizes](http://screensiz.es/phone)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) on Android Developers.

- LDPI   = 120dpi
- MDPI   = 160dpi
- HDPI   = 240dpi
- XHDPI  = 320dpi
- XXHDPI = 480dpi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of devices with their respective DIP buckets. It's far from official or complete, but it's the largest source I have found so far:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Thanks to @Blundell for listing it in the comments.