# How to give table width and height in millimeters in HTML

Tags: html

Is there a way to give HTML table width and height in millimeters?

```
<table border="1">
 <tr width="17mm">
        <td>gukgu</td>
        <td>gukgu</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Is this works?

Comment: You can't. That makes no sense, a pixel on one screen is not the same size as a pixel on another.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Does that matter?

Comment: @Kolink Yes, I have been burnt by this before :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850628/how-can-i-display-a-5mm-grid-at-the-proper-scale-in-a-web-browser

Comment: The resolution on different screens and screen sizes are different. Take the MacBook Pro with Retina, it has over a million pixels on a 13" screen, while my laptop has a lot less

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can set widths in millimetres. However, setting a width on a `<tr>` element usually doesn't do anything. Instead, consider adding this style to the table: `width:17mm; table-layout:fixed`

Comment: As the question title says “in HTML” and the question is tagged with “html” only, perhaps you should add that it cannot be done in HTML but can be done in CSS the way shown (though not accurately, as mentioned in comments).

Answer (score 4):

You can using `css`, however it is only recommended for print. For display on screen, you use `em`, `px` or `%`.

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
        <td style="width: 17mm;">gukgu</td>
        <td style="width: 17mm;">gukgu</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[See the manual](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

[See a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTxUK/)

Comment: That's not really reliable, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units , millimeters assume http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/images/pixel1.png (If you could edit this into your answer (also, the image kind of rocks) that would be great)

Comment: That's why I cautioned with it being not recommended.