# Determining the width of a webpage in inches

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a CSS stylesheet that uses media queries to change how a page is displayed based on how many inches it is in width (for instance, if it is smaller than 4 inches or being displayed on a handheld device, it assumes a more mobile-friendly LAF).

The problem I have is with its content. On the homepage, there is a dock-style interface that dynamically changes height based on the current height and width of the window so that the text and items never leave the screen. However, **my JS that determines this size does not know when the stylesheet has changed** for handheld devices or small screens, so the behavior continues unpredictably in this mode. **How can I use JavaScript detect when the page is less than or equal to 4 inches so that I can disable the auto-resizing of the then-reformed dock?**

Comment: You really can't in current browsers. Browsers simply don't tell the truth about their screen sizes, and often they simply don't know anyway. All you can do is code for sizes in (reported) pixel dimensions, and trust that the device manufacturers have designed reasonable screens. (And sometimes, as with the iPad Mini, the manufacturers fail.)

Comment: You'd probably be better off checking whether or not the dock is "visible", and turning the resizing off if it is not.

Comment: @Pointy, that's not entirely true. Each device has a certain resolution (PPI), if you know what device you are working with, you know how many pixels make an inch for that device. While not the best way to go about this by a long shot, it should be possible.

Comment: @Shmiddty well yes you could amass a database of useragent strings, but for example in the case of the iPad Mini even that won't work - there's no known way to tell an iPad Mini from an iPad 2. And you can't tell if I've got my laptop plugged in to a tiny LCD screen either.

Comment: @Shmiddty The "dock" is always visible. When the screen becomes <= 4 inches, it simply changes shape to look like a vertical list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a non-trivial problem.

Here's a link to a site that has a function (`getUnits`) to get the current computed style in a measurement unit of your choice (including inches) https://web.archive.org/web/20120427144951/http://upshots.org:80/javascript/javascript-get-current-style-as-any-unit

Using this function, you could check `if (getUnits(document.body, "width").inch < 4)`. The way this function works, for the curious, is by creating a temporary element in the desired measurement space and reading off the ratio to pixels. In this way you let the browser respond based on its own knowledge the device's PPI. So this is sort of a polyfill for `window.devicePixelRatio`, however browsers mostly lie about their PPI. For these purposes, though, it doesn't matter since they will be applying the same lie to your inch-unit CSS.

Comment: That script does not really work at all.  All browsers treat `1in` as being exactly synonymous with `96px` regardless of screen size.

Comment: @Pointy I think the point is that this way doesn't care whether the browser's right; it's synchronous with CSS measurements. If a browser is invented that is accurate with these measurements, then this method will still work.

Comment: @Pointy I think that's a personal bias and nonconstructive comment, especially considering that this solution works, seemingly 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't test this on real browsers, but it should work:

1. set a hidden `<div id="screen" style="display:none">` in your HTML.
2. In CSS, use media query like:

   ```
     @media screen
     { div#screen{color: blue;} }

     @media screen and (min-width: 13in)
     { div#screen{color: red;} }
   ```

Then you can read the `div#screen` color in JS to choose the actions.

Also, you should take windows resize event into JS consideration.

Comment: Just noting that I've changed your example CSS. Before, it was unclear what color the screen would be at exactly 13 inches wide. Now, it's blue by default, and red at or wider than 13 inches.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is read back the current style of a known element. By looking at something such as the width of an outer-wrapper DIV you can determine which stylesheet in your media query is in use.

Comment: Browsers lie about physical dimensions. If you style an element with "cm" or "in" measurements, the browser will apply a fixed pixel ratio that may or may not have anything to do with reality. As far as I know, all mobile and desktop browsers report that an inch contains 96 pixels, regardless of actual screen size.

Comment: @Pointy A lot do, yeah, but I find that iOS 5+ Safari does a good job with inchwise measurements

Comment: @Supuhstar http://jsbin.com/ovider/1 - all browsers treat `1in` as meaning `96px` regardless of actual screen dot pitch. In that respect, Safari can only do a "good job" if the screen happens to actually have 96 physical pixels per inch.

Comment: Actually, Safari could do a good job if the screen happened to have 192 physical ppi, because it reports 1in=96px, then scales any non-Retina-aware stuff by 2. But since the screen actually has 326ppi, this isn't even _remotely_ close.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the problem from the wrong angle. You shouldn't be thinking about inches. What you need to know is: given the device and browser how many pixels high should my page be?

The answer will lie in keeping a known set of devices and their respective pixel height.

An iPhone 5 is taller than an iPhone 4 for instance, this affects the effect you're going for.

Comment: [Browser detection is bad](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=browser+detection+is+bad). Also, I'm looking to measure the width, not the height.

Comment: This is unrelated advice. Browser detection is bad if you're checking for features or capabilities, you should use feature detection. Here you want a list of devices and their respective screen sizes. It's an unrelated issue.

Comment: So your solution is to make a Javascript database of all iOS, Android, Symbian, Blackberry, OS X, Linux, and Windows device and OS version ever made and all possible combinations of these?