# What version of the websites is going to be displayed on iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipad-mini

Some websites serve a different version on iPad and on iPhone.

What version of the websites is going to be displayed on iPad mini?

The mobile version as with iPhone or the regular version as with iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Since the iPad mini has the same resolution as the iPad and iPad2 the version that is displayed on those devices will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on how the specific website is detecting devices. If the site is simply checking how many pixels wide or tall the display is, the iPad Mini would evaluate the same as an iPad or iPad 2 and thus display the site the same way.

On the other hand (unlikely) it is possible that the site is checking device by PPI. But from everything I've read on this topic, checking PPI is often inaccurate and very unreliable.

Related: [Detecting the system DPI/PPI from JS/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279749/716216)