# Change DPI of canvas element in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, dpi

I'm looking to create a chrome application that allows the user to design a few different things using the canvas element. After they're done, I'd like to use a mask to crop out everything outside a specified area and then send the image to a printer. However, I need to be able to control the printed size precisely.

When I was making a similar app in python, it was a simple matter of setting the DPI to a ratio of the resolution to the dimensions I needed. I'm trying to find if there's a solution as simple as this one for HTML5.

I've found a couple posts asking for similar things, but they're unanswered and don't have a lot of activity.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Higher DPI graphics with HTML5 canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488849/higher-dpi-graphics-with-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is a bitmap (raster) format. You can not just increase the DPI without some horrible artifacts appearing.

You can however record all the drawing, strokes/fills etc, and then at print time create a larger canvas for print and scale up all the drawing commands to fit the higher resolution canvas. As long as you don't use bitmapped images or direct pixel manipulation the results will be good. Though large canvas formats can be problematic on some devices and browsers. A better way is to convert it all to a vector format like SVG and print that. Or skip the canvas altogether and draw to SVG.