# Using em's in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've created a responsive site and want to use `em`'s to control the font size.

I've set the body font base size to 64.5% as recommended to create a base of 10px.

However, though the sizing seems OK, it does not change with the size of the browser. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/XaUz9/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive Font Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size)

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/qK8j2/

In your example, you have explicity set the font sizes and there's nothing instructing the fonts to scale as the viewpont changes.

Setting
`body{ font-size:62.5%; }`
simply sets the font size (relative to the browsers default setting), it won't result in any scaling.

A couple of ways you achieve what you want is to either set sizes for h1, h2, p etc as the viepoint changes using [@media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) , eg

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

h1 {font-size:  2em }
h2 {font-size: 1em}
p{font-size:1em}
}
```

or you could set a default body font size at different viewpoints and the font sizes will scale relative to the setings you have at the head of your CSS file, eg

```
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

body{
font-size:90%;
}  
}
```