# How to make the text smaller when minimising the browser CSS

Tags: html, css

I have came across a problem, whenever I make my browser smaller the text stays the same and it doesn't go smaller. How do I make the text go smaller when I the browser gets smaller?

Please visit http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/PjbHs/ for my website

```
.home {
font-family:apple;
position:relative;
font-size:25px;
color:black;
top:20%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `CSS` media-queries, so when it's below/between a certain wide then change the font size - http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: What you want is [mediaQueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't play out to how i want it to

Comment: Can you add the media-queries you have tried, and the corresponding CSS to your post.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size

Comment: huh - saw that fiddle somewhere else too ? . Mediaqueries are the way to go - but if that is your website then I think "queries" are still to difficult. - no offense.

Answer (score 1):

As mention above you need to use media queries if you want to change your font-size (or any other CSS value based on browser / screen size)

Below is example based on Mobile Screen Size

```
// Work For All Other Screens Except the one which we redefine in bottom
.home {
font-family:apple;
position:relative;
font-size:25px;
color:black;
top:20%;
display:inline-block;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

.home {
font-size:20px;
}

}
```

You only need to define value which you want to change browser rest all values form above style and only change font-size to 20px on screen size 320px

Keep in mind you need to include libraries like https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond in your page to support older browsers

Answer (score 0):

This css should work for you... simply adjust/delete the query breaks as needed and adjust the font size as well.

```
.home {
font-family:apple;
position:relative;
font-size:25px;
color:black;
top:20%;
display:inline-block;
}

    @media all and (min-width: 1281px){ 
    .home{font-size:25px;}
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {    
        .home{font-size:22px;}
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) { 
        .home{font-size:18px;}
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        .home{font-size:16px;}
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        .home{font-size:14px;}
    }

    @media all and (max-width: 320px) {
        .home{font-size:14px;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using viewport units but it does require a small amount of JS/JQ due to a minor bug.

http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

http://caniuse.com/viewport-units tells browser support

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mEgji)

**CSS**

```
p {
  font-size:1vw;
}
```

**JQ**

```
causeRepaintsOn = $("p"); /* could include any text related tags */
$(window).resize(function() {   causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to not use px for font sizes, as each browser has a different standard font size to begin with. however there is an alternative which can give you the result you want across all browsers, old and new.

css:

```
 #px {
 font-size:25px;  /*this was the size you want*/
 }

 #percent {
 font-size:160%;   /*this is what it is in % but give you the support for crossbrowser coding*/
 }
```

incase you want to try it out here is the html to show you the difference

html:

```
<p id="px">HELLO</p>

<p id="percent">HELLO</p>
```