# Maintaining Responsiveness When Adding Custom Text Classes to Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to add my own class called "article-title" that is much bigger than twitter bootstrap's default H1 font size.

Could someone please outline what steps need to be taken in order to keep things responsive?  I'd like to make sure that on smaller screens the text shrinks appropriately.

thank you

Comment: If this isn't super easy, than bootstrap doesn't seem to be doing a great job in aiding your workflow. Just saying... bootstrap is THE WORST!!! get out now while you still can!!! it has tons of insane type styles you'll have to fight with, when it's really just so easy without that Frankenstein's monster.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries and change the font-size based on the screen size

For example, this media query changes the font-size when your screen size is 320 pixels or below:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .article-title { font-size: 2em; }
}
```

example above demonstrated in stack question below

[Responsive Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size)

good luck

Comment: (keep in mind the differences with the `@media screen only and() {}  vs. @media () {} for older browsers)

Comment: What does the @media tag do?

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you? http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Set the `font-size` in em for `<h1>` and then change font of body using px.