# Change font height and width

Tags: html, css

I want to change not the `font-size` of text, but two independent properties relative to its width and height.
So, by applying `font-width: 50%` to this element:

[image]

the text would be stretched to half:

[image]

Is this possible to do using CSS?

Comment: "if your lazy here is a fiddle".  Not sure how that's going to go down. With this jquery could help. Where you create a number and change 2 css properties. Just to be clear you want to control width and height of text independently. How are you controlling the width at the moment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size
This might help

Comment: There is a font-width-stretch property in css but it's currently unsupported by all the major browsers

Comment: You can use font weight.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform) has the [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale%28%29) function for this:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: scale(.5, 1);
}
```

```html
<p>This is text.</p>
```

Use the two numbers in the function for X- and Y-axis respectively.

Answer (score 13):

You can try scaling the font in x direction.

```css
p{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.5);
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing I can find is font-weight

It accepts not only bold,normal but also numeric values. 100-900 in 100 increments.

```
 . Paragraph {font-weight :700;}
```

This combined with height properties should help but will not give you complete solution

Also look at spacing properties as you can reduce the the width of the words that way

```
  letter-spacing: 2px;
```

Comment: Width is not weight.

Comment: this is a simple solution, I like it.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `svg` text with `preserveAspectRatio="none"` allow text deformations and very precise positioning.

To adjust, It's all about the `viewBox`. The rendering stays natively responsive to browser resizes.

The text stays select able.

```css
.title {
  width: 540px;
  height: 40px
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px
}

.side {
  width: 270px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 160px;
  transform: rotate(44deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="30" viewBox="0 0 100 15" width="100%" height="100%">
   <foreignObject x="5" y="1" height="100%" width="100%">
      <div>
        Hello world!
       </div>
     </foreignObject>    
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="30" viewBox="0 0 400 200" width="100%" height="100%">
    <foreignObject x="55" y="15" height="100%" width="80%">
      <div>
       The best way to use a hello cheer for introducing players is to have one cheerleader use a megaphone or loudspeaker to announce the players names and stats.
       </div>
     </foreignObject>     
  </svg>
</div>


<div class="side">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="30" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="100%">
    <foreignObject x="5" y="15" height="200%" width="100%">
      <div>
       NOW WITH COLORS!
       </div>
     </foreignObject>     
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Tip:** For complex stuffs, flyers making, using the `cm` css unit works very well.

Comment: is there a "auto" property value to adjust the viewbox automatically to show everything  ? (when you don't know the length of the text).

Comment: You could just use regular CSS, like: `overflow-wrap` on the `div`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: thanks ! i'll try it & will  let you know (on stg else right now)