# Unable to show progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've created this simple javascript quiz application. I coded a progress bar too which works perfectly well on my laptop offline, but when I try uploading the files on [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/VaKMBJ) , the progress bar doesn't show up.

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```js
var allQuestions = [
 { 
  question: "Before Mt. Everest was discovered, whaich mountain was considered to be the highest mountain in the world?",
  choices: ["Mt. Kilimanjaro", "Kanchenjunga", "Mount Everest"],
  correctAnswer:1
 },

 {
  question: "Does England have a 4th of July?",
  choices: ["Yes","No","I don't know"],
  correctAnswer:0
 },

 {
  question: "What is Rupert the bear's middle name?",
  choices: ["Bear","He doesn't have one!", "The","Rupert"],
  correctAnswer:3
 },
 
 {
  question: " What can you never eat for breakfast? ",
  choices: ["Dinner","Something sugary","Lunch","Supper"],
  correctAnswer:0
 },

 {
  question: "If there are three apples and you took two away, how many do you have?",
  choices: ["One","Two","None"],
  correctAnswer:1
 },

 {
  question: "Spell 'Silk' out loud, 3 times in a row. What do cows drink?",
  choices: ["Milk","Water","Juice","Cows can't drink"],
  correctAnswer:1
 },

 {
  question: "Which is heavier, 100 pounds of rocks or 100 pounds of gold? ",
  choices: ["100 pounds of rocks","100 pounds of rocks","They weigh the same"],
  correctAnswer:2
 },

 {
  question: "Can you spell 80 in two letters?",
  choices: ["AI-TY","It's not possible","EIGH-TY","A-T"],
  correctAnswer:3
 },

 {
  question: "What question must always be answered ''Yes''?",
  choices: ["What does Y-E-S spell?","Will everyone die someday?","Does everyone have a biological mother?","Are you a human?"],
  correctAnswer:0
 },

 {
  question: "How many sides does a circle have?",
  choices: ["The back","None. It's a circle","Two","Four"],
  correctAnswer:2
 },

 {
  question: "What has a tail but no body?",
  choices: ["A human","A coin","A cloud"],
  correctAnswer:1
 },

 {
  question: "What word in the English language is always spelled incorrectly?",
  choices: ["It's possible to spell anything right as long as you learn it","Shakespeare","Onomatopoeia","Incorrectly"],
  correctAnswer:3
 },

 {
  question: "When do you stop at green and go at red?",
  choices: ["Watermelon!","Traffic light!","Garden"],
  correctAnswer:0
 },

 {
  question: "What rotates but still remains in the same place?",
  choices: ["Bottle (spin the bottle game)","Clock","Stairs"],
  correctAnswer:2
 },

 {
  question: "How can you lift an elephant with one hand?",
  choices: ["Truck","Use both hands!","Use a lever","There is no such thing"],
  correctAnswer:1
 } 
];
 var currentquestion=0;
 var correctAnswers=0;
function setupOptions(){
  $('#question').html(parseInt(currentquestion)+1+". "+allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
      var options = allQuestions[currentquestion].choices;
      var formHtml='';
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        formHtml += '<div><input type="radio" name="option" value="'+i+'" id="option'+i+'"><label for="option'+i+'">'
        +allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[i]+'</label></div><br/>';
      }
      $('#form').html(formHtml);
      $("#option0").prop('checked', true);  
};

function checkAns(){
 if($("input[name=option]:checked").val()==allQuestions[currentquestion].correctAnswer){
  correctAnswers++;
 };
};

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".jumbotron").hide();
 $('#start').click(function() {
     $(".jumbotron").fadeIn();
     $(this).hide();
   });

 $(function() {
  $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
   max: allQuestions.length-1,   
   value: 0
  });
 });

 setupOptions();

 $("#next").click(function(){
   checkAns();
   currentquestion++;
   $(function() {
       $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
          value: currentquestion
       });
     });
   if(currentquestion<allQuestions.length){
    setupOptions();
    if(currentquestion==allQuestions.length-1){
     $('#next').html("Submit");
     $('#next').click(function(){
      $(".jumbotron").hide();
      $("#result").html("You correctly answered " + correctAnswers + " out of " + currentquestion + " questions! ").hide();
      $("#result").fadeIn(1500);
     });

    }
    
   };
 }); 
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15em;
  font-family: 'Chonburi', cursive;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

.ui-widget-header {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: #FF7860 !important; 
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
}

h3, #next {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

#result {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #036;
}

input[name="option"] {
  float:left;
}
#form div{
  margin:auto;
  max-width: 205px;
}

#progressbar {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: none; 
  width: 50%;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  margin:5em;
  padding:3em;

}
/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}


/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #79BD9A;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    color: white !important;
} 
body{
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
       -o-transition: width .6s ease;
          transition: width .6s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chonburi' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="start" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Let's Begin</a>
<br/>
<div class="well jumbotron">
  <h3 id="question"></h3>
  <br/><br/>
  <form id="form">
    <div><input type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked><label for='option0'></label><br/></div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="option1"><label for='option1'></label><br/></div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="option2"><label for='option2'></label><br/></div>
  </form>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" id="next" class="button">Next</a><br/>
  <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

I have some other issues as well which are not specific to codepen.io:

1. The heading "Quiz" isn't responsive.How do I fix that?
2. The text options aren't perfectly aligned with the `radio` buttons?
3. How can I fix the position of the webpage, when moving from one question to the other?

Comment: I guess the problem lies in sourcing the code ,in an incorrect order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to show progress bar

The `height` rule on `.progress-bar` appears to be the culprit.

> 1. The heading "Quiz" isn't responsive.How do I fix that?

You can use a **viewport unit** so the font changes in response to the viewport. `16.7vw` is equivalent (near enough) to the value you're using (`15em`).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size) related question for more information.

[Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) that support the **viewport units**.

> 2. The text options aren't perfectly aligned with the radio buttons?

Not sure what you mean by this. You have the text centered - do you not want it to be centered?

> 3. How can I fix the position of the webpage, when moving from one question to the other?

By this I'm assuming you don't want the page to jump to the top whenever you click next? If so, on the `click` event for the "next" `button`, expose the event object and prevent the default action via `event.preventDefault();`.

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPrqLm)**

Comment: Thanks man, btw, what i meant by the second question was that the text options and the `radio` buttons don't seem to have the same base line.This becomes pretty evident in question no.9,12&14.

Comment: adding // to the height property does solve the problem, but even if I comment out the height property it works completely fine! @Yass