# how to make my font size responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make some big title responsive.  I tried a few things such as: this [Link](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). But it didn't work.

CSS

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px; /* Required margin for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigationchanges. */  
}


#page-wrap {

  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
    font-family: Brush Script MT,cursive;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;

}

#welcome {
    @extend .title;   
}

#to {
    @extend .title;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;   
}

#mp{
    @extend .title;
    text-align: right;

}


.full { 
   background-image: url('../img/beach-bg1920-1080.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;

}



/*******navbar elements *********/
.navbar-inner {
    background:transparent;
    border: solid#ffffff 2px;
}

.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: $hover-color;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: white;
}

.navbar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-brand:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*******navbar elements End *********/
```

HTML

```
    <div id="page-wrap">           
        <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
        <h2 id="to">to</h2>
        <h1 id="mp">My Portfolio!</h1>
    </div>
```

You can't see the word "My portfolio".  i am trying to move everything to the left. in other words, I just want to make sure that this is going to look alright on mobile devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive Font Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size)

Comment: I tried those answers but didn't work, i got my link from that page, too. @KyleMessner

Comment: What is the exact behavior you are after?

Comment: So, the title is big so big that cover the front page.  So, if I minimize the window the text doesn't change the side

Comment: Right but do you want it to change size precisely as in the `font-size: #vw;` example or do you want it to jump to a pre-determined size as in the media queries example?

Comment: change size.  I just want to make sure that it will look nice in mobile devices.  But, anything will be useful...

Comment: Have you linked 100% of your CSS/HTML? With just what you've given I've been able to get `vw` to work.

Comment: yeap that is all my code, i just started to create my portfolio 2 days ago.  So, there is no too much code

Comment: Please, share your solution so I can compare it with my code and see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this code.

```css
#welcome{
  font-size:10vw;
}
#to{
  font-size:6vw;
}
#mp{
  font-size:12vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">           
  <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
  <h2 id="to">to</h2>
  <h1 id="mp">My Portfolio!</h1>
</div>
```

We can make font size responsive by giving responsive unit to font.
px unit is not responsive, whereas percent (%), vh/vw, em, rem units are responsive.

In given example link (css tricks) they've used viewport unit to make font responsive.
viewport unit is nothing but vh,vw.
vh is: viewport height and vw is viewport width.

If you give vw unit to font, it'll change/ get responsive according to your screen width.

Comment: yes, it works.  But, there is a problem.  Not sure if you saw that I am using: `text-align: center and right` so when I change the size of the window everything get out of place.  Is there a way to also make everything look nice if the window is small; like a mobile size or something

Comment: Do you want "Welcome to my portfolio" sentence in one line?

Comment: Nop, just make sure that if you move everything to the left, so everything goes to the left.  right now if you try to minimize the window from right to left for some reason "My portfolio" word get hided by the window.  And, yes letter get smaller, but they don't show up on the page, they hide!

Comment: I just attached a picture. =)

Comment: Have you written any other css? Any reset css etc.?

Comment: I just posted my css (all lines)

Comment: http://codepen.io/vinayasonawane/pen/xVrKrZ
Check this pen. I've used same css and html code. It's working well even if I reduced browser width to check responsiveness.

Comment: So if I delete my `#page-wrap` it does work...But I need my site wrap up

Comment: got it..I will use .container from bootstrap

Comment: Check it again.
Now I've added wrapper, same like yours.
http://codepen.io/vinayasonawane/pen/xVrKrZ

Comment: Ok.. So if you're using bootstrap, use container or container-fluid.
Hope it'll help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing `150px` to `10vw` worked for me.

```css
.title, #welcome, #to, #mp {
  font-family: Brush Script MT,cursive;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#to {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#mp {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">           
  <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
  <h2 id="to">to</h2>
  <h1 id="mp">My Portfolio!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vw instead of pixel 
for more details https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

```css
.title {
  font-family: Brush Script MT, cursive;
  font-size: 15vw;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#welcome {
  @extend .title;
}

#to {
  @extend .title;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13vw;
}

#mp {
  @extend .title;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
  <h2 id="to">to</h2>
  <h1 id="mp">My Portfolio!</h1>
</div>
```