# Resize ul and li element with text to window size

Tags: css

So I'm developing a web page, and I'm making it now responsive. I managed to get everything responsive except the main menu nav.

It's a **ul** element and it has **li** inside with text. Here are some pictures about the problem

Full webpage:

[image]

On mobile:

[image]

I just want to adjust the text or the ul element to fit without making another line.

Here's the css **ul** element:

```
.main-menu ul {
    display: table !important;
    background-color: #98B709;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And the **li** element:

```
.main-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing works...

Thanks and hope you guys can help me!

Comment: you can move your navigation in a burger menu

Comment: Reduce the `width`, `font-size`, `padding` or  `margins` of the `li` elements (for which I doubt will fit all in one line). Or put every `li` in a new line making it take full width. Or make a toggle button with a sidebar opening.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful Stackoverflow post that should answer your question:

[Responsive Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size)

And I experienced that changing font size and other problematic parts from px to em generally helps to make is more responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different font size e.g

vw  Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport

vh  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation that does not use display:table, which I always avoid.

The important bit you can play with is the 'width' of the 'li' element.  If you really want to squash them all on one line, you can make this a very small %.

If you do use the second line, the 'text-align:center' in the 'ul' element will keep everything centered, instead of floating left as you have it now.

I use this code block all the time; it's a common problem.

```
#main{
width:100%;
}

#main ul {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#main li {
width:10%;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 8px;
}
```