# WordPress different looks in same browser - zoom issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I am newbie in Wordpress and have a quick question.

I have two computers at home: Computer1 and Computer2

In computer1 (bigger screen), my Wordpress site looks clean with small fonts in 100% zoom in Chrome.
However, in computer2 (smaller screen), my Wordpress site looks ugly with big fat fonts in 100% zoom in Chrome. When I change to 75% zoom in browse, it looks same as what I see in computer1.

Is there way I can write code in style.css, so that either I or viewers visit my site can see good looking site without changing zoom in the browser?

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size

Comment: You may also want to ask at wordpress.stachexchange.com. Your question doesn't contain any code for now, not even a link to an example page. In this curcomstances it's hard to help you.

Comment: There are so many differnet reasons for this, especially as you're comparing two completely different machines. These machines may have different accessibility options enabled. Although the screens are bigger/smaller... could it be resolutions that are making them appear oddly to you?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the font size with the media queries in your CSS. Something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

It will change the font size of the body when your screen size reach 768px or 480px.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different font or better version of the font. I'm not a WordPress expert but I hope this helps. 
e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  @import https:small-screen-font.com
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  @import https:big-screen-font.com
}
```