# Why is this font-size not working in the media query

Tags: html, css

I have media queries , but in one, the font-size is not working

```
     @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-devicewidth:     667px)  
{ 
#topnav             {   padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
#topnav a           {   font-size:28px;}
#topnav h1          {   font-size:55px;}
#content            {   float:left;width:100%;margin: 20px 0px  0px 0px;  }
#content p          {   font-size:25px; color: #AAAAAA;text-align:justify;padding:0px 20px 10px 20px; }
#content h1         {   font-size:40px; color: #AAAAAA;line-height:140%;padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;text-align:center; }
```

Comment: it is the #content p that is not working , although the color is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error in `max-devicewidth`.

You should inspect your `#content p` element in a browser and look from what line in what css file it takes its font-size attribute, you're probably overriding it somewhere.

EDIT:

how to inspect : if you use chrome, right click on the element, click on inspect. You will have the html page as nodes, in which you can navigate. Be sure you have click on the element you want to inspect, and then look what styles are applied

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: probably it is the overriding problem, the other attribute do work. I only do not know how I can inspect that ....

Comment: what I discovered , it works in google chrome on my pc , but the font size is not working on my iphone6

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {

 h2{
        font-size: 4.3vw;
    }

}
```

[Responsive Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size)

Answer (score 0):

put queries.css file after(below) the style.css file in the html file