# How do I resize text inside a table using media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, font-size

I have this html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newcss.css"/>
```

...

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>General Inquiries:</td>
      <td>Email@email.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone:</td>
      <td>#########</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mailing address:</td>
      <td>123 Some St. 123 456</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: white;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 90%;
}

td {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 730){
    table, tr, td, tbody, thead {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

However, when I resize the window to below 730, the font size does not change on any of the elements listed in the media query. Any Ideas?

Comment: May be it's helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size

Comment: thanks guys love you all, I forgot the px, stupid mistake lol

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to add the unit in your `max-width` statement! Just add `px` after the number and it will work (click the "View Fullscreen" link below the snippet in order to be able to see the change):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: white;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 90%;
    background: #666; /* added this for the snippet so we can see the text at all */
}

td {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 730px){
    table, tr, td, tbody, thead {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>General Inquiries:</td>
      <td>Email@email.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone:</td>
      <td>#########</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mailing address:</td>
      <td>123 Some St. 123 456</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `px` after the `730`, so try

```
@media (max-width: 730px){
    table, tr, td, tbody, thead {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

By the way, if possible, don't insert text inside the `<td>` directly, add a `<span>` or a `<p>` to wrap the text inside.

Comment: It seems that something got lost when you posted your answer. It's not clear what you're referring to and what OP is supposed to add!

Comment: Good answer, strange advice. There's nothing wrong with inserting text directly into `<td>` tags...

Comment: @J.Titus I know that, for SEO purposes, is better to wrap the text on the website with a <span> or a <p> tag. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Wrapping text in a table has nothing to do with search engine optimization.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in your media query

```
@media (max-width: 730px){
    table, tr, td, tbody, thead {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, great you're getting involved in answering questions in order to help others. However, this answer would be more helpful if you pointed out the mistake instead of just posting the corrected code.