# Fit text into flexbox container

Tags: html, css, fonts, flexbox, navbar

I have a navigation bar with image in the middle. Looks similar to this:

```
<nav class="navigation">
   <ul class="navigation-list-1">
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#add-info">Add info</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><img class="logo" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6f4af2d2d158"></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#form">Form</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And style:

```
> .navigation-list-item {
list-style: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.logo {
  position:absolute;

width: 10vw;
left:calc(50% - (10vw/2) - (10px/2));
background: cornflowerblue;
border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
}

ul{
  display:flex;
  margin-left:-40px;

}
li{
  flex:1;
  background:yellow;
  border:1px solid green;
  height:70px;
  line-height:70px;
  text-align:center;
}

li>a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Now, if text in navigation item is longer than particular length, the text is spliting into next line and going outside the bar so it doesn't look good. How to make text in container always to be in one line?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` is about it with CSS. You could write a complicated JS function to make it happen but I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for Your reply. That's working. However I need to add a media query for smaller screen size. Anyways, that's sort of answer for my question. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: One more question: is it possible to make font responsive? I mean, when I make screen smaller, the container are getting smaller as well, but font-size is fixed and gettin sticked together very close. Is possible to make the font-size responsive?

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size) helps.

Comment: Yes it does... Thanks a lot a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Good option for start is to add css style for text: `white-space: nowrap;`
Another good way is to set the `font-size` in vw units. Font will be responsive depending on screen size.