# How to set font size to exact physical size?

Tags: css

I am confusing about css units a lot. I just want to know one thing:

If I want my text's font-size is exact 4mm physically in any devices and any cases.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is the [`mm` unit](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#mm) in CSS, it does not necessarily reflect the real physical size when being shown on a screen. There is no way to ensure exact physical dimensions on all devices and all cases.
CSS units for screen media are [anchored](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#anchor-unit) to the `px` unit which is not based on physical pixels but on the [*reference pixel*](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#reference-pixel).

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s length. For a nominal arm’s length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm’s length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

The reference pixel thus highly depends on the device you are using and it may or may not result in correct physical dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS supports `mm` as a unit, you could use `font-size: 4mm;`. This, however, should only get used for printing stylesheets (cf. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html), so you really try to avoid those units and just use units like `px` or `em` for other purposes.

If, however, you really (!) need to use those units, you could also use those units (but I would strongly advise against that).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example code:

```
<div id='testdiv' style='height: 1in; left: -100%; position: absolute; top: -100%; width: 1in;'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  dpi_x = document.getElementById('testdiv').offsetWidth * devicePixelRatio;
  dpi_y = document.getElementById('testdiv').offsetHeight * devicePixelRatio;

  function setFontSizeForClass(className, fontSize) {
      var elms = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
      for(var i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
          elms[i].style.fontSize = String(fontSize * dpi_y / 96) + "px";
      }
  }

  setFontSizeForClass('h1-font-size', 30);
  setFontSizeForClass('action-font-size', 20);
  setFontSizeForClass('guideline-font-size', 25);
</script>
```

More details on what it does and how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190669/1915854