# Font size responsiveness in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, responsive-design

In React native, is the font size responsive on its own?
for example, if I give `fontSize:10`  to a Text component, will it automatically increase/decrease based on the size of the phone? If not, how to make it responsive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive font size in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size-in-css)

Comment: Units aren't used in react native as far as I know

Comment: don't know much about react native but try changing `10` to `"10px"`

Comment: cannot use pixels in react native or any other units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize)The font size is automatically adjusted according to the size of the screen.
Try applying this method.

```
yarn add react-native-responsive-fontsize
npm install react-native-responsive-fontsize --save
```