# How do I make auto fontSize in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to use the same function of `fontSize()` in mobile view to make it responsive but I don't know to do it. This is what I'm using in window view

```
document.getElementById('hakdog').onload = function () {func()};

function func() {
var str = document.getElementById("voter").innerHTML;
var a = str.length;

if(a >= 40) {
    voter.style.fontSize = "18px";
} else if(a >=30) {
    voter.style.fontSize = "22px";
} else {
    voter.style.fontSize = "27px";
}
}
```

Is there any same function for mobile view? I only know some function but I know its not responsive

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width() < 480) { 
     $('h1').css('font-size','10px');
     $('h2').css('font-size','8px');
     $('h3').css('font-size','6px');
     $('h4').css('font-size','4px');
}
});
```

**EDIT**

I was trying to make it responsive using java just like on the first code I given, normal `.css` is not gonna work since its only going to give for `h1, h2, h3, etc.` I was pointing out that I wanted to make the responsive if the full name reached 40 letters then the `fontSize` would be `18px` same with other functions given

**EDIT 5:30pm MARCH 29**

This is what I tried so far but didn't work as what I expected.

```
document.getElementById('hakdog').onload = function () {func()};
function func() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    function resizes() {
        if($(window).width() < 480) {
            var str = document.getElementById("voter").innerHTML;
            var a = str.length;

            if(a >= 40) {
                voter.style.fontSize = "9px";
            } else if(a >=30) {
                voter.style.fontSize = "10px";
            } else {
                voter.style.fontSize = "15px";
            }
        }
    }

    resizes();
    $(window).resize(resizes);
  
})
}
```

Comment: Consider using CSS instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive font size in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size-in-css)

Comment: Hmm not recommended since I was using an automatic fontSize changer if the name reached its limit

Comment: You can consider to use em instead of px  if you want a more reactive size.

Comment: So are you getting a problem in only mobile view ? or you are asking in-general for how to auto-resize fonts based on the length of content?

Comment: @innocent, yes im only getting a problem in mobile view only, to make it responsive based on the length of the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i meant for auto sizing for every device

```
var wid = $(window).width();

if(wid < 320) {
var str = document.getElementById("voter").innerHTML
var a = str.length;

if(a >= 40) {
    voter.style.fontSize = "9px";
} else if(a >= 25) {
    voter.style.fontSize = "11px";
} else {
    voter.style.fontSize = "15px";
}
}
```

Thanks for everyone commented out!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Made changes to include the font size based on the length of the content.

---

This should work. You can check this out on the full page in the below code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function resizeMe() {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
      if ($("#name").text().length < 5) {
        $('h1').css('font-size', '46px');
      } else {
        $('h1').css('font-size', '10px');
      }
      $('h2').css('font-size', '8px');
      $('h3').css('font-size', '6px');
      $('h4').css('font-size', '4px');
    } else {
      $('h1').css('font-size', '20px');
      $('h2').css('font-size', '18px');
      $('h3').css('font-size', '16px');
      $('h4').css('font-size', '14px');

    }
  }

  resizeMe();
  $(window).resize(resizeMe);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="name">Helo</h1>
<h2>Yes</h2>
<h3>Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h3>
<h4>okkkkkk</h4>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what i wanted to do in js, Since I said that I need to change the `fontSize` depending on length content

Comment: You can add the length of the content inside the if block and based on it the size it will get set

Comment: This is what i tried, i will edit my post

Comment: Because im not using any `h1, h6` I only use `paragraph` with `classes` so its not really accurate your answer to my question.

Comment: hmm ok, you can add the paragraphs or apply the following to classes I will remove this or edit it to change based on the length of the characters

Comment: Edit will be okay, no need for deletion for others

Comment: @新Acesyyy I added the change I was telling. If you want a more dynamic approach. Also, I would recommend using CSS As that would be more efficient and easy to do (for eg, You can add the classes based on the content length). Also, You can checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to change 'px' to 'rem', 'rem' resize in relation to the size of the screen.