# How to change font size in library (analogue)?

Tags: r, font-size

I wonder about working with library (analogue). Is there any possibility to increase the font size there? I use the Stratiplot function.

I believe there is no such option at all.

I need to increase the font size in Stratiplot function.

The script example is below:

```r
Stratiplot(x = tas_pmf,
           y = tas_pmf_depth,
           type = c("poly", "g"),
           zones = pmf_zones_man,
           xlab = "Abundance, %", 
           ylab = "Depth, cm")
```

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+Stratiplot+font+size) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive font size in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size-in-css)