# Javascript download multiple files and concatenate into a single file

Tags: javascript

I am supporting a website development work. Two binary files are downloaded to client browser upon request. The two files can come from two different sources.

The requirement is to concatenate both the files into a single file. Creating a single file in JavaScript and writing first downloaded content followed by second downloaded content is also acceptable.

Is this doable in JavaScript using [FileAPI](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) or any other related APIs?

Do I need to explore Chrome/Firefox Extension to achieve the same?

Comment: What does "merge" mean?

Comment: Oops! better I will refer as concatenate.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Two binary files you literally concatenate? How is the resulting file useful or readable? Did you mean put the files in an archive like a zip file?

Comment: Too avoid server load this has been done. The first file will be of few MBs and has user specific data, where as the remaining large file will be downloaded from a different server, say Amazon S3 like that. The user application installed has the capability to read and understand the file content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but if I understood correctly you can store your files into `ArrayBuffers` and then merge them:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Uint8Array based on two different ArrayBuffers
 *
 * @private
 * @param {ArrayBuffers} buffer1 The first buffer.
 * @param {ArrayBuffers} buffer2 The second buffer.
 * @return {ArrayBuffers} The new ArrayBuffer created out of the two.
 */
var _appendBuffer = function(buffer1, buffer2) {
  var tmp = new Uint8Array(buffer1.byteLength + buffer2.byteLength);
  tmp.set(new Uint8Array(buffer1), 0);
  tmp.set(new Uint8Array(buffer2), buffer1.byteLength);
  return tmp.buffer;
};
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/72lions/4528834

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) you can read more about `ArrayBuffers` and you definitely should check MDN's [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Comment: Thanks! It helps. Is there any max size limit applied for the ArrayBuffer?

Comment: @SetV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823225/do-arraybuffers-have-a-maximum-length