# Uint8Array invalid typed array length for larger array buffer

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I'm reading a file as an array buffer via:

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFile);
```

I'm then taking that array buffer and trying to create a Uint8Array via:

```
reader.onload = e => {
  let arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(e.target.result, 0, 
  e.target.result.byteLength);
```

I've also tried just:

```
let arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
```

In both cases when I upload a file with a byte length of 198873088 it works fine. However when I try a larger file of 1564725248 i get the following in the first case:

```
Invalid typed array length: 1564725248
```

and this in the second case:

```
Invalid typed array length: undefined
```

I thought the cap was 2^32 - 1 which would be 42949672995, can anyone explain why there's a problem with the length?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17823225/1048572), it's implementation-dependent. What browser on what system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (32-bit) on a windows 10 enterprise 64-bit with 16 gigs of ram

Comment: i didn't even think browser js allowed access to gigs of ram...

Comment: I'm getting "RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 40".  From this:
new Float64Array(window.Module.HEAPF64.buffer, pointer, 40);
HEAPF64 is another typed array, length 2097152.  Pointer is 5276224. 
 This has been working correctly for months.  Maybe it's time to reboot.  Or, take a vacation.

Comment: It was off the end.  So, it's not just the length that can cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit), I get the following results. Each test performed after a hard reload on blank page.

```
a=new Uint8Array(256*256*256*128) // Triggers Uncaught RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 2147483648
a=new Uint8Array(256*256*256*127) // Works, array length 2130706432
```

However more interesting is that I can trigger an "Aw, Snap" without getting the exception. :

```
a=new Uint8Array(256*256*256*127 + 64) // Doesn't work, triggers "Aw, Snap!" page
```