# How to calculate an image's DPI?

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, image-processing

I have an app that the user needs to upload images, but these images must be at least 300 DPI. I only have the height and width information for this image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting the system DPI/PPI from JS/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279749/detecting-the-system-dpi-ppi-from-js-css)

Answer (score 1):

DPI is the measurement of pixel density - it depends on the resolution (with and height you have) *and* the printed or displayed dimensions of the image. 300x300px image printed on 1"x1" paper will have 300DPI, but if you print it at 10"x10" paper it will have just 30DPI.

To calculate the DPI, divide the resolution by size.